# Thrust: selectively move elements to another vector

Tags: stl, cuda, thrust

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do the following using Thrust: vector A has a million floats, they have some particular order. I want to *move* to vector B every element *x* in A for which *x*>7.0 **such that** the order of elements is maintain in both vectors A and B. Importantly, only a tiny fraction of elements need be moved. Efficiency is more important for my code than elegance.

My idea was to use `thrust::copy_if` from A to B and then `thrust::remove_if` on A. But I don't know the exact number of elements to be copy, and since apparently the memory for B must be allocated in advance, another counting operation is necessary. An inelegant way to skip the counting operation is to pre-allocate "enough" memory for vector B.

Using `thrust::remove_copy_if` has much the same problems: you need to allocate memory for B in advance, and also it doesn't actually remove anything from A so another `thrust::remove_if` is required anyway.

Another idea I had was to use `thrust::stable_sort` with some custom-made comparison functor, to push all elements I want out to the end of A, and then somehow figure out how many there are and `thrust::copy` them to B. This also looks pretty inelegant...

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track with thrust::copy_if. Just allocate two more buffers of the same size as the first one. Then copy_if > 7.0f to the first one and copy_if <= 7.0f to the second one. Allocating buffers of the same size as the original buffer is fine as long as you know there's room, and 1 million floats only takes up 4MB.

**Edit:**

I did a performance comparison of the `copy_if` and `stable_partition` approaches. On my card, a GTX660, `stable_partition` took around 150% as long as `copy_if` for "split" values of `0.1f`, `0.5f` and `0.9f`. I added tests to ensure that both methods are stable (maintain the order of the values).

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <curand.h>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/partition.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

#define CHECK_CUDA_CALL(x) do { if((x)!=cudaSuccess) { \
    printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);\
    return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0)


#define CHECK_CURAND_CALL(x) do { if((x)!=CURAND_STATUS_SUCCESS) { \
    printf("Error at %s:%d\n",__FILE__,__LINE__);\
    return EXIT_FAILURE;}} while(0)


#define SPLIT  0.1f

struct is_low
{
  __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const float x)
  {
    return x <= SPLIT;
  }
};


struct is_high
{
  __host__ __device__ bool operator()(const float x)
  {
    return x > SPLIT;
  }
};


class EventTimer {
public:
  EventTimer() : mStarted(false), mStopped(false) {
    cudaEventCreate(&mStart);
    cudaEventCreate(&mStop);
  }
  ~EventTimer() {
    cudaEventDestroy(mStart);
    cudaEventDestroy(mStop);
  }
  void start(cudaStream_t s = 0) {
    cudaEventRecord(mStart, s); 
    mStarted = true;
    mStopped = false;
  }
  void stop(cudaStream_t s = 0)  {
    assert(mStarted);
    cudaEventRecord(mStop, s); 
    mStarted = false;
    mStopped = true;
  }
  float elapsed() {
    assert(mStopped);
    if (!mStopped) return 0; 
    cudaEventSynchronize(mStop);
    float elapsed = 0;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsed, mStart, mStop);
    return elapsed;
  }

private:
  bool mStarted, mStopped;
  cudaEvent_t mStart, mStop;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const size_t n = 1024 * 1024 * 50;

    // Create prng
    curandGenerator_t gen;
    CHECK_CURAND_CALL(curandCreateGenerator(&gen, CURAND_RNG_PSEUDO_DEFAULT));

    // Set seed
    CHECK_CURAND_CALL(curandSetPseudoRandomGeneratorSeed(gen, 1234ULL));

    // Generate n floats on device 
    thrust::device_vector<float> vec_rnd_d(n);
    float* ptr_rnd_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(vec_rnd_d.data());
    CHECK_CURAND_CALL(curandGenerateUniform(gen, ptr_rnd_d, n));

    thrust::device_vector<float> vec_low_d(n);
    thrust::device_vector<float> vec_high_d(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      EventTimer timer;
      timer.start();
      thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator iter_end;
      iter_end = thrust::copy_if(vec_rnd_d.begin(), vec_rnd_d.end(), vec_low_d.begin(), is_low());
      thrust::copy_if(vec_rnd_d.begin(), vec_rnd_d.end(), vec_high_d.begin(), is_high());
      timer.stop();
      std::cout << "copy_if: " << timer.elapsed() << "ms" << std::endl;

      // check result
      thrust::host_vector<float> vec_rnd_h = vec_rnd_d;
      thrust::host_vector<float> vec_low_h = vec_low_d;
      thrust::host_vector<float> vec_high_h = vec_high_d;
      thrust::host_vector<float>::iterator low_iter_h = vec_low_h.begin();
      thrust::host_vector<float>::iterator high_iter_h = vec_high_h.begin();
      for (thrust::host_vector<float>::iterator rnd_iter_h = vec_rnd_h.begin();
          rnd_iter_h != vec_rnd_h.end(); ++rnd_iter_h) {
        if (*rnd_iter_h <= SPLIT) {
          assert(*low_iter_h == *rnd_iter_h);
          ++low_iter_h;
        }
        else {
          assert(*high_iter_h == *rnd_iter_h);
          ++high_iter_h;
        }
      }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      thrust::device_vector<float> vec_rnd_copy = vec_rnd_d;
      EventTimer timer;
      timer.start();
      thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator iter_split = 
        thrust::stable_partition(vec_rnd_copy.begin(), vec_rnd_copy.end(), is_low());
      timer.stop();
      size_t n_low = iter_split - vec_rnd_copy.begin();
      std::cout << "stable_partition: " << timer.elapsed() << "ms" << std::endl;

      // check result
      thrust::host_vector<float> vec_rnd_h = vec_rnd_d;
      thrust::host_vector<float> vec_partitioned_h = vec_rnd_copy;
      thrust::host_vector<float>::iterator low_iter_h = vec_partitioned_h.begin();
      thrust::host_vector<float>::iterator high_iter_h = vec_partitioned_h.begin() + n_low;
      for (thrust::host_vector<float>::iterator rnd_iter_h = vec_rnd_h.begin();
          rnd_iter_h != vec_rnd_h.end(); ++rnd_iter_h) {
        if (*rnd_iter_h <= SPLIT) {
          assert(*low_iter_h == *rnd_iter_h);
          ++low_iter_h;
        }
        else {
          assert(*high_iter_h == *rnd_iter_h);
          ++high_iter_h;
        }
      }
    }

    CHECK_CURAND_CALL(curandDestroyGenerator(gen));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\rd\projects\cpp\test_cuda\Release>test_cuda.exe
copy_if: 40.2919ms
copy_if: 38.0157ms
copy_if: 38.5036ms
copy_if: 37.6751ms
copy_if: 38.1054ms
stable_partition: 59.5473ms
stable_partition: 61.4016ms
stable_partition: 59.1854ms
stable_partition: 61.3195ms
stable_partition: 59.1205ms
```

Comment: Oh, wow! It seems two `copy_if` operations are faster than a one `stable_partition`! Can you guess why it is?. Thanks for the code, I'll see later if it also holds for complex data types.

Comment: I think it's a [space/time trade-off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff). `copy_if` requires two extra buffers of the same size as the source buffer. `stable_partition` has the restriction that, either, it must work within that single buffer, or it must create buffers in the background and copy the results back to the source buffer.

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question, I finally found `thrust::stable_partition`, which is more efficient and elegant than all "copy_if"-alternatives. It just moves all elements that fail to satisfy a predicate to the end of the array and returns the start of the second sequence. Pointer arithmetic gives the size of B, but in fact it's not necessary anymore:

```
thrust::device_vector<float>::iterator iter = thrust::stable_partition(A.begin(), A.end(), pred)
thrust::device_vector<float> B(iter, A.end())
A.erase(iter, A.end());
```

Comment: Cool! It definitely looks cleaner. I'm curious about performance vs. the `copy_if` approach.